# How to restrict users to access a file on a web server?

Tags: php, mysql, security, permissions, file-permissions

Hi I have a file which updates database. I use it for a cron job, but it also works if someone accesses it like this: http://myweb.com/files/file.php

And I concerned tha users can access it and mess with a database. Is there a way to hide it from users, but keep it so I can edit it and cron job can execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep it in a directory which in not web accessible. If you want to keep it in its current location, then in the code you can add a check to see it is is being called from browser or by crawlers (using user-agent, referrer, etc) and if it is called from browser or by crawlers display an error message else let it execute.

Comment: So say all my website files are located in /root/ directory, so I should place this file outside it right?

Comment: Yes. If your web accessible directory is /root/ then create a directory at the same level (e.g. /cron/) and place your cron file inside it. So that it cannot be accessed through the web.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev No, I meant if its being called by browser or crawlers, display the error message. Updated the solution to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

How you solve it depends on your hosting environment, but if you need http access and are using Apache webserver, you can configure access rights in a .htaccess file. If you use IIS, configure file permissions and configure access rights in IIS manager. By the way, the best solution and most secure wold he to keep the file away from public area, and invoke the file directly from the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tricks that can help you.

1. You can check REMOTE_IP. If it's not localhost, die.
2. You can verify that a special 'secret' parameter is passed. Like http://myweb.com/files/file.php?access_key=6rNPY6PhXPDf. If it's not present or is invalid, die.
3. Place this script in a folder that can't be accessed via web (that is, outside your www-root)